# Angular: observable instantiated in ngOnInit with switch map is completed but view is not updated when I use async pipe (only after mouse click)

Tags: angular, asynchronous, observable, angular2-changedetection

I have strange issue with change detection, switchMap and async pipe in Angular.

Imagine following (simplified) code in the component:

```ts
public ngOnInit (): void {
    this.sellerProducts$ = Observable.combineLatest([
        this.offerProductsService
            .emitChangeSource
            .filter((offerProducts: Product[]): boolean => offerProducts !== null),
        this.store.getObservable(),
    ]).switchMap((params: any[]): Observable<any> => this.getSellerProducts(params[1].seller.id));
}
```

with following (simplified) template:

```html
<ng-template #loading><app-loader></app-loader></ng-template>
<div *ngIf="sellerProducts$ | async as sellerProducts; else loading" class="form-group row">
    <pre>{{sellerProducts | json}}</pre>
</div>
```

The problem is when I use `switchMap` and async pipe, Angular doesn't run check after `switchMap` completes. The view is update when I click with the mouse because Angular runs `ngDoCheck`.

I created also video to demonstrate my problem:
https://youtu.be/LZdPGkhSXfU

**Any ideas how to say async pipe to run check for it without a mouse click?** (e.g. run detectChanges or run in Zone)

p.s.: When I subscribe in `ngOnInit` and I will not use async pipe it works fine. I would just like to take advantage of async pipe.

Comment: were you able to resolve it?

Comment: @OferHerman not really, I rewrote the component which helped. Probably problem with some internals of the change detection. After that long time I can only think that I had some problem with having some of the components OnPush and not handling it correctly...

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is most likely not about the async pipe. Async pipe is internally using ChangeDetectorRef and calls markForCheck() that is registering the component path for change detection when a value is emitted. But change detection doesn't happen at that moment already. Here is where your assumption about the Zones might be the right thought.

But this would require knowledge about the inner workings of your `this.offerProductService`, `this.store` and 'this.getSellerProducts' observables. I would expect that some emission of values will happen outside zone by callbacks executed from third party libraries or other events that aren't zone aware.

If you don't have an idea about which observable will cause that, you can use `(NgZone.isInAngularZone()` to determine if your code runs in zone when it calls `next(...)` within the observable.